# WocoomerceProduct Variation Range Slider

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have WordPress wocoomerce and I want similar like this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-variation-range-slider/) for my attribute option. I do not want the select options.

When I installed this plugin and config it is not working and in console it show error not found when I check the plugin path of JS there is no such file there.

woo-product-variation-range-slider/assets/js/slider_validation.js

ANY paid plugin like this OR need to go for custom one.

Thanks

Comment: You should read this and contact this person: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/does-not-work-on-ssl-https/

Comment: @LoicTheAztec ok i will contact to developers

Comment: @LoicTheAztec do you any suggestion instead of using that plugin which can full fill my requirement.

Comment: Without a plugin like this, this is just a custom development… So no I don't have any. You should try to understand this plugin code, to make it yours.